# Device information thru webbrowser

Tags: android, ios, mobile, browser, mobile-browser

I am looking for unique identifiers within webbroswers to pinpoint whom the browser is dealing with on a mobile device.
My questions is, is there (apart from screen size information) any other information available or not available when using a web browser on a mobile iOS or Android devices compared to a browser on a pc or mac?

I have googled this a while, but can't really find anything helpful. Any links/references would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have got to work with are the attributes of the navigator object. See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_navigator.asp for details.

Comment: Ok, but is there more information than that? I mean more compared to a normal browser? I know the GPS is possible and more accurate since most hand held devices have a GPS chip (Position is also possible on a PC or Mac, I know), but that requires the users consent. I am looking for such data yet without the users consent.

Comment: That is your lot, according to the DOM spec. GPS is covered by navigator.geolocation, which is an HTML5 extension. If you are trying to identify the user from the DOM, just forget it. That is what sandboxing is all about. You can use a cookies for that sort of thing though.

Comment: Yes, I know. Hence my comment. Yet my goal is to get as much information about the user as possible in order for me to make certain decisions in the flow of my application. Just browser information won't be enough.

Comment: You can do slightly more server side, but not very much. You can pull all the request headers, which will give you absolutely everything. It will not be very much though.